# How to read the binary file generated by the Unity profiler?

Tags: unity, profiler

I'd like to know how can I read the binary file generated by profiling Unity game and how can I save it on external hard disk.

Comment: Maybe the answer of this stack overflow question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809888/how-can-i-save-unity-statistics-or-unity-profiler-statistics-stats-on-cpu-rend